# Under what circumstances can you abbreviate forms like ないとならない?

Tags: grammar, abbreviations

For example, if you have this sentence:

> 急がないとならない

You can just say:

> 急がないと

But what if the sentence is...?

> 急がないとならないからあとで話そうね

Can you omit ならない there? It would turn into:

> 急がないとからあとで話そうね

It doesn't sound right to me but I want to be 100% sure it can't be omitted. It also applies to other forms with the same meaning. For example, if you have 急がなければならない, can you shorten it to 急がなきゃ even if it's not the end of the sentence? Or 急がなくてはならない to 急がなくちゃ, under the same circumstances?

Comment: 「ないと」as you say is abbreviated, but is also an expression in its own right, meaning "is indispensable; absolutely necessary". See [Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8). So I guess the answer to your question may be: 「ないと」 (the short form) can be used when the expression makes sense in the context.